# Why does Msbuild NoTargets csproj requires TargetFramework?

Tags: msbuild, csproj

I want to package some tools as a nuget and am using the [Microsoft.Build.NoTargets](https://github.com/microsoft/MSBuildSdks/blob/main/src/NoTargets/README.md) project SDK format to achieve the same.

As mentioned in the docs, NoTargets is used when the project file does not compile any assembly. However, it needs a `TargetFramework` property to be set.

msbuild fails with NETSDK1013 if I don't specify some `TargetFramework` property.

Why does msbuild mandate that `TargetFramework` be specified for the NoTargets SDK csproj?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this is required for it to load in VS: VS checks if the project contains `TargetFramework` or `TargetFrameworks` in the xml to load sdk-based projects in the "new" project system (the thing that powers the IDE integration of the project). Otherwise it would use the legacy system that would not understand the features the SDK uses and either not load or give you a bad experience.

The MSBuild errors could be fixed in the SDK by defaulting the property but that will still fail IDE integrations.

Also note that the SDK imports other SDKs that are meant for .NET projects (language-independent over F#/C#/VB) and so you should get features like NuGet restore or packing working without much friction when a `TargetFramework` is set (even if it could be defaulted to whatever the SDK is basdded on in the NoTargets itself as mentioned)